# How do I sort Firebase values stored under user.uid?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, so I'm trying to create a leaderboard for an app. Users store their "points" inside a Firebase database, under their user ID.

The JSON looks like this:

```js
- users
  - hJfEgXkyaKPckchL3kx8rpZ58Ew2
    -LV6c8E5rRD4_mQqsb6Q
      - name: "Lin Manuel Miranda"
      - points: 120
  - mlIBrdjT8CfIURQEAhLFPzzUFQg1
    -LV7I6d8LeuWFLH5MRKy
      - name: "Emily Blunt"
      - points: 200
```

"mlIBrdjT8CfIURQEAhLFPzzUFQg1" and "hJfEgXkyaKPckchL3kx8rpZ58Ew2" are the corresponding user.uid.

How can I write my code so that I am returned with a list of their "points" in ascending order??

My .ts file and .html:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// firebase imports
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { User } from 'src/models/login.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { reference } from '@angular/core/src/render3';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  users: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.users = this.db.list('/users/').valueChanges();
    const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/');
    const ref = usersRef.orderByKey();

    ref.once('value').then(function(snap) {
      snap.forEach(function (childSnap) {
        const pkey = childSnap.key;
        console.log(pkey);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
    <div class="cards" *ngFor="let user of users  | async">
      <ion-card>
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{user.name}}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle id ="points">{{user.points}}</ion-card-subtitle>
          </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

As of now, the .ts returns the user IDs.

Any help would be very much appreciated!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
const ref = usersRef.orderByKey();
```

use

```
const ref = usersRef.orderByChild('points');
```

in your query.

Your angular fire code will be updated like this:

```
this.users = this.db.list('/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('points')).valueChanges()
```

Comment: how should I set the database reference? Should I do: this.users = usersRef.orderbyChild('points');

Comment: see these docs : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: you are using angular fire so it has different syntax than normal javascript

Comment: Sorry, but the code is returning [object Object] through the html.

Comment: its because the value changes return raw snapshot on which you are showing your view. You have to process the data before giving it to view. see the examples in the link I have commented earlier.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the link. I think I got it now thanks.

Comment: Please mark the answer correct as well to help others seeing your question on stackoverflow.